# SvelteKit - getSession and handle functions in hook.ts aren't executing

Tags: sveltekit

As it already says in the title, the handle and getSession functions in my project don't execute.

Here is my hook.ts file:

```
import type { GetSession, Handle } from "@sveltejs/kit"
import {parse} from "cookie"

export const handle: Handle = async({event, resolve})=>{
    console.log("Handle")
    const cookie = await parse(event.request.headers.get("cookies") || "")
    event.locals.user.lang = cookie.lang || "sl"
    const response = await resolve(event)

    return response;
}

export const getSession: GetSession = async(request) => {
    return {
        user: {
            lang: request.locals.user.lang
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if I missed something that's crucial for it to execute, but yeah. I searched a long time for a solution but I did not find anything, even if I followed some tutorials step by step.

Comment: Have you placed the `hooks.ts` inside the `src` folder?

Comment: I checked on my local project, and both seem to fire like the comment above, have you placed the hooks.ts inside the src folder?

Comment: @ShrijiKondan Oh damn, thank you, had it in the routes folder xD

Comment: @yongjulee Yeah i found the mistake, i had the file in the routes folder